# Extract values from a set according to a given probability distribution

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, boost, statistics

I have to tackle this problem:

```
vector<int> myset={1,2,3,4};
vector<double> distribution ={0.01,0.1,0.3,0.59};
```

I have to pick a number of values from *myset* according to given *distribution*. Actually *distribution* and *myset* aren't fixed. They are of the same dimension, but this dimension can change and be  pretty large too. I could uniformly extract a number in the range [0 100] and do like this:

```
int extracted_numb;
int numb = rand(0,100);
if(numb<1)
  extracted_numb=myset[0];
else if(numb<11)
  extracted_numb=myset[1];
else if(numb<41)
  extracted_numb=myset[2];
else
  extracted_numb=myset[3];
```

But I repeat, I don't know in the real case the dimension of *distribution* and *myset* (because is a user parameter) and thus I don't know how many *if*  to do.

I ask if there is a good algorithm for this problem, and maybe some native library of C++ or in Boost that already accomplish it

(I'm using Boost 1.63 and C++11)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With C++11, use [`random::discrete_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution) to select an index into `myset`. (Boost has a similar function.)

Example (adapted from the cppreference link):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> myset = {10,22,35,47};
    std::vector<double> distribution = {0.01,0.1,0.3,0.59};
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::discrete_distribution<> d(distribution.begin(), distribution.end());
    std::map<int, int> m;
    for(int n=0; n<10000; ++n) {
        ++m[myset[d(gen)]];
    }
    for(auto p : m) {
        std::cout << p.first << " generated " << p.second << " times\n";
    }
}
```

([Live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a922e3b242e9ac2f))

Comment: Impressive timing. I knew this one, but 5 minutes is too fast for me

Comment: Very smart solution. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much